# How to intercept a request, then load the content

Tags: php

So i have the following code:

```
  header('X-Powered-By: Mecanik1337');
    header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
    header('X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block');
    header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff'); 
    header("X-Message: Why are you seeing this? Bad boy!");

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['SOMECOOKIE'])){ # not interesting.
        setcookie('SOMECOOKIE', true,  time()+3600); // every hour :)
        echo ' Please wait....'; 

    <br><script>
                var counter = 5;
                var seconds = "";
                setInterval (function()
                {
                counter--;
                if(counter < 1)
                {
                window.location = "index.php";
                }
                else
                {
                if(count <= 1) seconds = " second";
                else seconds = " seconds...";
                document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter + seconds;} }, 1000);

                <noscript>
                <h1 style="color:red;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
                <noscript>
        die(); # die xD
    }
```

Now what it should do, is to check if SOMECOOKIE is set, if not show this message and count 5 seconds then reload the page as it should be, but what it does now is really just reloading and reloading the page every 5 seconds.
This is not the full code i will add some checks against bots after, but right now i just want this to work.
I wish i could make this "check" before every request but that`s not possible since it is reloading again and again.

Comment: Is there a "id=count" element in the HTML? Otherwise the innerHTML statement will fail. But why don't you just send a "refresh" header? `Header('refresh: 5');`. The countdown may be cool for some, but simplicity works best.

Comment: @lserni - thank you for answering, i need to countdown, doing refresh with headers won`t help me, can you help me with the ID ? you mean generate a unique ID for each client?

Comment: @Iserni - add an answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript code you have,

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter + seconds;
```

This locates a DOM element whose id (hence the "get element by *id*") is "count" and places the text you want in there.

But the element must exist, otherwise document.getElementById will return NULL, and you will be trying to modify the innerHTML of NULL. Which can't be done.

To create such an element, just output a proper HTML document:

```
setcookie('SOMECOOKIE', true,  time()+3600);
print <<<DOCUMENT
<html>
    <body>
        Please wait <div id="count"></div>
        <noscript>
            <h1 style="color:red;">
                 Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.
            </h1>
        </noscript>
        <script>
            // Your script goes here.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
DOCUMENT;
// It is very important that the above line starts at column 1 (no 
// spaces before the 'DOCUMENT'), that there is nothing after the ;
// just in case, and that no other triple-angle-bracket section in
// this file is tagged as DOCUMENT. You can add another section with
// a different tag, such as DOCUMENT1 or HELLOWORLD.
die();
```

Comment: well that didn`t work ;/ counter does not work anymore, neither the refresh :(

Comment: I have prepare a JSFiddle with the sample code. The fiddle outputs the data in a different order, but the "pieces" are the same. I see no reason why it shouldn't work when done in PHP. What error do you get? Is it a PHP error, or a browser-side one? This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/07Loo6mL/

Comment: @Iserni - i have been testing, but no success. When i combine it with php, it does not do what i want... Check if SOMECOOKIE is there, if not show Please wait bla bla bla...